# How to use map on List of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to solve a problem which has to make a .csv file into list of lists (**list1**) and then I have to use map function to extract the desired output into another list (**list2**) from **list1**

the csv file contains data like

```
Last name, First name, Final, Grade
Alfalfa,   Aloysius,49,   D-
Alfred,    University,48,   D+
```

After making the .csv into list I have to check for the marks if the student will be selected or not by using map on the list1

So here I code it like this

```
import csv
from curses.ascii import isdigit

def selection(lis):
    for x in lis:
        if(x.isdigit() and int(x) > 50):
            return lis
    
list1=[]
list2=[]

with open('D:\C++\Programs\Advanced Programming\grades.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:
        list1.append(line)

for i in list1:
    r = map(selection, i)
    R = list(r)
    list2.append(R)

print(list1)

print(list2)
```

**list1** prints correctly

```
[['Alfalfa', '   Aloysius', '49', '   D-'], ['Alfred', '    University', '48', '   D+']....]
```

But my **list2** is printing

```
[[None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None].....]
```

I am not getting how to use map on list of lists. Why it is printing none. Please help to solve it.

Comment: what should your final output look like?

Answer (score 0):

just update ur selection function as

```py
def selection(lis):
    return lis if (lis.isdigit() and int(lis) > 50) else None
```

map sends a single item to the function not the entire list

Output will be

```
[['boo', 'foo', '53', 'a']]
[[None, None, '53', None]]
```

you can return anything else other than None if you want in selection function's else statement

Comment: I have to use map function on first list1 to get the list2. not directly from the csv file

Comment: @SatyabrataKar map sends each value individually to the function, not the entire list, see updated ans

Answer (score 0):

**Issue #1**

The first problem is that you are going a little too deep. The code

```
for i in list1:
    r = map(selection, i)
```

is sending individual list items to `selection` when you are expecting the entire `list` to be sent to `selection`. You want to change that code to just be

```
r = map(selection, list1)
```

**How this results in a bunch of `None`s**

If you add some print statements around the place to debug what is going on you would see that

`for i in list1:` makes `i` be a single list such as `['Alfalfa', '   Aloysius', '49', '   D-']`

Then `map` sends each item from our list `i` to the `selection` function. So `def selection(lis):` doesn't actually recieve a list, it will receive an item from the list such as `Alfalfa` or `49`.

Then we have `for x in lis:` where we check each character in `Alfalfa` to see if it is a number greater than `50`. Is `A` greater than 5n, No. Is `l` greater than `50`, no. And so on. The for loop finishes, and whenever a function finishes without returning anything, None is returned. Map then moves on to the next item in the list until it gets to a number such as `51` where it will check each character, a `5` and a `1` in this case. Since `5` is not greater than `50` and `1` is not greater than `50`, we continue on. As you can see you will never end up with a number greater than `50` since we are in a little too deep checking each individual character instead of the whole item.

**Issue #2**

The second problem is you want to use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) instead of map to ignore anything that returns `None`. `filter` will loop over each item sending each item to `selection` and will add the item to our list `r` only if `selection` returns something true.

The following code does what you want.

```
import csv

def selection(lis):
    for x in lis:
        if(x.isdigit() and int(x) > 50):
            return True

list1=[]
list2=[]

with open('D:\C++\Programs\Advanced Programming\grades.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:
        list1.append(line)


r = filter(selection, i)
list2 = list(r)

print(list1)

print(list2)
```

**How I'd solve this type of problem**

Below is how I would go about solving this problem. I'm using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of map or filter.

```
import csv

csv_file = 'D:\C++\Programs\Advanced Programming\grades.csv'

with open(csv_file) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fh)
    
    headers = next(csv_reader)
    data = list(csv_reader)

passing_grades = [x for x in data if x.isdigit() and int(x) > 50]

print('passing grades: ', passing_grades)
```